# How to disable all buttons except one in the click event handler?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing below code. Please someone can tell me that here in switch statement how can I disable all other buttons when any one of them is pressed. I actually want the user to know his luck only once in this application.

```
  namespace tryAppWFA
   {
      public partial class mainWindow : Form
       {
    public mainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button=(Button)sender;
       switch (button.Name) { 
            case "button1":
               textBox.Text = "Hey ! you may get a car after one year";

               break;
            case "button2":
    textBox.Text = "Hey ! you may get a big super duper House after a year";
                break;
            case "button3":
                textBox.Text = "something";
                break;
            case "button4":
                textBox.Text = "something";
                break;
            case "button5":
                textBox.Text = "somehting"
                break;
           case "exit":
                Environment.Exit(0);
                break;
           default:
            break;

        }

       }
      }
      }
```

Comment: Assuming you know all the button names, just write a method to find the control using their name `this.Controls.Find("contril_name", true).FirstOrDefault()` and the disable it.

Comment: are you plannin on disabling all buttons or only the ones that are not clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following to achieve this : 

first set your buttons `Tag` property to the buttons name in your load event of the form :

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Tag = button1.Name;
    button2.Tag = button2.Name;
    btnExit.Tag = btnExit.Name;
    //and so on...

}
```

then what you want to do is iterate through your controls and disable the ones that are not the clicked one : 
***Note that here its considered that the buttons are not in a groupbox, if that was the case you would have to iterate through your container which would be the groupbox in that case.***

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Button item in this.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(Button)))
    {
        if (item.Name == btnExit.Name)
            continue;
        item.Enabled = false;
    }
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    switch (button.Name)
    {
        case "button1":
            textBox.Text = "Hey ! you may get a car after one year";
            break;
        case "button2":
            textBox.Text = "Hey ! you may get a big super duper House after a year";
            break;
        case "button3":
            textBox.Text = "something";
            break;
        case "button4":
            textBox.Text = "something";
            break;
        case "button5":
            textBox.Text = "somehting";
             break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

*edit: i also removed the exit button from the switch statement.*

Comment: your answer proved to be really helpful.. i remove the exit button from this switch statement and this event handler. I created another separate event handler for that. but still exit button disables when i press any button. I actually wanted to disable all buttons except that exit button. So please tell me how can I do that.

Comment: @mac please see the editted answer and if it solved the issue mark as the answer. :)    (considering your exit button is named btnExit)

Comment: thanks it really solved the problem. I am going to mark this as answer. Thanks again